# Audience targeting in Sharepoint-Hosted add-in

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, audience-targeting, audiences

Is it possible to apply audience targeting to the list items in Sharepoint 2013  Sharepoint-Hosted add-in while retrieving those items using JSOM or REST API without explicitly filtering out.

I couldn't find any reference regarding this, can some someone clarify regarding this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now audience targeting is not supported for CSOM or REST.

There is a corresponding [uservoice](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329220-sharepoint-dev-platform/suggestions/15146988-provide-a-means-to-do-audience-filtering-for-list). You can vote for it, may be we can speed up MS a bit for implementation :)

Comment: That uservoice was posted in 2014, but still has very few votes. :(

Comment: Is there any way/tricks/hacks to use the same functionality in Apps

Comment: Only workaround via permissions, for example.

Comment: This [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/176638/61070)  says that we can still do CAML query based on target audience. Is this really possible. I tried but no luck.